# Overview Map to show always whole map

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I use open layers 4 and I want that Overview Map to show always a whole map in central position, only the red box should move around overview map.

Comment: give as some snap of your project and code what you did so far as we can help you

Comment: I try to create new View as parameter for ol/control/OverviewMap

Comment: Look at this example, is this what you want http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/overviewmap-custom.html

Comment: NO, it this example overview do not show always whole map and red box is in central postion, I want box to move around map and map to be always in central postion ...

Answer (score 1):

Specifying a overview map view with a single resolution and extent (i.e. center constraint) will work as long as the main map isn't panned so far that the center constraint on the overview is exceeded.  e.g. this will give an almost global overview

```
        new ol.control.OverviewMap({ 
            view: new ol.View({
                resolutions: [ol.tilegrid.createXYZ().getResolution(0)],
                extent: [0, 0, 0, 0]
            })
        })
```

If you are using 2180 trying to show a world overview is going to cause reprojection errors!  The overview will also need to be in EPSG:2180 with resolution and center constraint appropriate for that

```
        new ol.control.OverviewMap({ 
            view: new ol.View({
                projection: 'EPSG:2180'
                resolutions: [ ?? ],
                extent: [x, y, x, y]
            })
        })
```

where ?? needs to be large enough to get all of Poland (and a bit more) in the overview and x, y is somewhere in the center of Poland in EPSG:2180 coordinates.

Comment: is this correct? resolutions: [ol.tilegrid.createXYZ().getResolution(0)],

Comment: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Object(...) is not a function

Comment: That returns the first resolution of a standard XYZ grid (where the world is a single tile).  It's working for me on v4.6.5 with an OSM main map.  Is your main map using 3857 projection?